# How to get input textfield value and pass it with data-ajax-url="@Url.Action() in cshtml

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor

I have a function in my controller that receives two dates and its working fine if I pass the parameters hardcoded my problem that i can't figure how to get the value from my text field and pass them to the function, I do not want to use form, my cshtml code is  :

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="input-field">
                <input asp-for="StartDate" type="text" class="datepicker" autocomplete="off" id="sDate">
                <span asp-validation-for="StartDate"></span>
                <label class="active" for="StartDate">Inicio</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="input-field">
                <input asp-for="EndDate" type="text" class="datepicker" autocomplete="off" id="eDate">
                <span asp-validation-for="EndDate"></span>
                <label class="active" for="EndDate">Termina</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" id="btnsBuscar">
            <div class="actions clearfix mt-35 text-right">

                <a id="btnVid" href="#"  data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("VideosClientReport", "Report",new {Date1= StartDate", Date2="EndDate"})" data-ajax-begin="showLoader()" data-ajax-complete="hideLoader()" data-ajax-update="#content" class="active btn waves-effect waves-light pull-right ml-28">Buscar</a>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and also i tried to use this function, its work but i can't reload my PartialView like the upper code data-ajax-update="#content" the function is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnVid").click(function () {


            var s = $('#sDate').val();
            var e = $("#eDate").val();

            alert(s + " " + e);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("VideosClientReport", "Report")', 
                data: { StartDate: s, EndDate: e},
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#content").load(response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: You need Javascript.

Comment: what should i do with javascript can you give me more info, please

Comment: Learn how to interact with the DOM and send AJAX requests.

Comment: I know how to make a call as script using ajax and its work but how do i reload my div like this data-ajax-update="#content" command that i am using  look to the update up

Comment: reload with what ? the response coming back from your ajax call ? You can use `.html` method to update the inner html of that div. Ex : `$("#content").html(response);` assuming `response` has some HTML markup/text content

Comment: ok i will try it thx

Comment: Also your `data-*` attributes are not being used anywhere in your javascript code.

Comment: Thanx its worked perfectly  if you like make a replay so i can mark it as an answer

Comment: You can self answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to Shyju post I solved my problem by using this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnVid").click(function () {
                var s = $('#sDate').val();
                var e = $("#eDate").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("VideosClientReport", "Report")',
                    data: { StartDate: s, EndDate: e},
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#content").html(response);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```